# SQL Server Datetime convert from string

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

Sorry asking again..i have a problem when i tried to insert datetime from field.
The problem is Syntax error converting datetime from character string.i'm using SQL Server 2000. below is my code

```
startDate = Trim(Request("StartDate"))
endDate = Trim(Request("EndDate"))

SELECT *
FROM tbl_Master
WHERE DoDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '"&startDate&"', 102)
                     AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '"&endDate&"', 102)
```

Really appreciate for that.Thanks

Regards
-GreenCat-

Comment: Where are you trying to run this code from?

Comment: sql query analyzer and my asp code

Comment: Why don't you converted in PHP ahead?

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @startdate as varchar(10)
declare @enddate as varchar(10)

set @startdate='10/02/2011'
set @enddate = '10/31/2011'


select * from [dbo].[Test]
where _date between Cast(@startdate AS DATETIME) and cast(@enddate as DAtetime)
```

Comment: this code you already set the date right.how if i get the date from '"&startDate&"'"

Comment: I would do the validation before calling the stored procedure and passing the parameters in to SQL.  Validate the input in your application's code, then pass to SQL.  Why pass crap data to SQL if you can catch it and deal with it before hand.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should check the format of your date string that is getting parsed on the request.  The 102 in the Convert, tells SQL what format to attempt to process your string date in.  Refer to this page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to see what format you're using.

If you're still having troubles, can you post what the value of `Trim(Request("StartDate"))` is?

I'm not near my development PC, but you could try format 106...

```
startDate = Trim(Request("StartDate"))
endDate = Trim(Request("EndDate"))

SELECT *
FROM tbl_Master
WHERE DoDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '"&startDate&"', 106)
                     AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '"&endDate&"', 106)
```

Comment: i will let you know later.away from PC a while

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
declare @startDate datetime
declare @endDate  datetime

set @startDate = value of startdate

set @endDate = value of end date

SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.Entry_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,@startDate, 102)
                 AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @endDate, 102)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in SQL Query Analyzer:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '11-OCT-2011', 106)
```

I'm guessing your issue is how your adding your date to a SQL string.  I'm guessing you have something like this in your ASP code...

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Master " & _
         "WHERE DoDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '"&startDate&"', 106) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '"&endDate&"', 106) "
```

If so, that should work, if it isn't please give us the strSQL text. Have you tried putting a spaces between your ampersands? '" & startDate & "'

Comment: "SELECT * FROM DataReport WHERE location like '%" & slocation & "%' AND DATE BETWEEN #" & Format(datefrom,"mm/dd/yyyy") & "# and #" & Format(dateto,"mm/dd/yyyy") & "#;"...i try this code but mismatch format..zzz

Comment: What does that SQL string return?  Can you do a message box with the text value so you can get the actual SQL query that you're sending to the database?

Comment: can you reply give me your email sir so that i can send you my full code..thanks

Comment: If you want to share your code, use code paste or something like it to share.  I may not be able to answer your question, or look through your code. http://codepaste.dev7studios.com/